# iOS RxSwift - how to “disconnect” an observable?

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I am building an aggregator class that connects multiple observables and emits a single sequence of emissions from these observables:

5 inputs from sources go in, one input comes out from `ReplaySubject`.

**Is there a way to manage subscriptions within this aggregator to allow one of the sources to “disconnect” without breaking the whole chain?**

Would keeping a dictionary of `[Observable: Subscription`] help to be able to cancel a specific subscription?

Comment: The question is too vague. Can you post some code showing how these subscriptions are combined?

Comment: A subject can be terminated by manually calling ‘dispose’ on it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might benefit from having something like a [Store object](https://gist.github.com/dtartaglia/a102153cb29be9c4354e0bbdebf1d5ca) (reproduced below.)

Your store is bound to your input sources. (as in `myInput.bind(to: myStore).disposed(by: bag)`) and the outputs are bound to the store's state. (as in `myStore.state.bind(to: myOutput).disposed(by: bag)`)

The inputs can disconnect by completing and the outputs can disconnect by disposing the associated disposable.

The reducer's job is to convert an input into an output.

```
//
//  Store.swift
//
//  Created by Daniel Tartaglia on 3/11/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Haneke Design. MIT License
//
import Foundation
import RxSwift


class Store<State, Action> {

    init(initialState: State, reducer: @escaping (State, Action) -> State) {
        state = actions
            .scan(initialState, accumulator: reducer)
            .startWith(initialState)
            .share(replay: 1)
    }

    let state: Observable<State>

    private let actions = PublishSubject<Action>()
}


extension Store: ObserverType {

    typealias E = Action

    func on(_ event: Event<E>) {
        actions.on(event)
    }
}
```